# React - maintaining a single selection out of multiple answers

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I have `<App />` as smart component, for which I put all the logic of my trivia quiz:

```
const decodeHTML = (html) => {
  return he.decode(html)
}

function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState([])
  const [selectedAnswerId, setSelectedAnswerId] = useState("")
  const [selectedAnswerByUser, setSelectedAnswerByUser] = useState([])
  console.log("Selected Answers: ",selectedAnswerByUser)


  useEffect(() => {
      async function getData() {
          try {
              const res = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
              const data = await res.json()

              const quizWithIds = data.results.map(question => {
                const incorrectAnswers = question.incorrect_answers.map(answer => ({
                  id: nanoid(),
                  text: decodeHTML(answer),
                  isCorrect: false,
                }));
                
                const correctAnswer = {
                  id: nanoid(),
                  text: decodeHTML(question.correct_answer),
                  isCorrect: true,
                };

                const answers = [...incorrectAnswers, correctAnswer]

                return {
                  ...question,
                  answers
                }
              })
              console.log('Data from API:', data);
              console.log('Quiz with IDs:', quizWithIds);

              setQuiz(quizWithIds) // This is my state!
          } catch (error) {
              console.log("Error fetching data: ", error)
          }
      }
      getData()
  }, [])



  function toggle(answer) {
    console.log("Clicked answer:", answer);
  
    // Check if the answer is already selected
    const isSelected = selectedAnswerByUser.includes(answer.id);
  
    // If selected, remove it; otherwise, add it to the array
    setSelectedAnswerByUser(prevSelectedAnswers => {
      return isSelected
        ? prevSelectedAnswers.filter(id => id !== answer.id)
        : [...prevSelectedAnswers, answer.id];
    });
  
    setSelectedAnswerId(answer.id);
  }
  

  

  const quizElements = quiz.map(obj => (
    <Quiz
        key={obj.id}
        id={obj.id}
        question={decodeHTML(obj.question)}
        answers={obj.answers} // Pass the entire answers array to Quiz
        toggle={toggle}
        selectedAnswerId={selectedAnswerId}
        selectedAnswerByUser={selectedAnswerByUser}
        />
  ))

  return (
    <div className="quiz-page">
      {quizElements}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and `<Quiz />` as dumb component that holds only the conditional rendered styling when an answer is selected.

```
export default function Quiz(props) {

    const { question, answers, toggle, selectedAnswerByUser } = props;
    

    const defaultStyle = {backgroundColor: "", border: "1px solid #D6DBF5"}
    const selectedStyle = {backgroundColor: "#D6DBF5", border: "none"}


    return(
        <div className="trivia-obj">
            <h2>{question}</h2>
            <ul>
                {answers.map((answer) => (
                    <li
                        key={answer.id}
                        onClick={() => toggle(answer)}
                        // Refactor the code below:
                        // If the selected answer matches with the answer id && no answer is selected apply selectedStyle
                        // If selected answer includes answer.id && one answer is already selected
                        // apply selectedStyle on the selected answer, apply defaultStyle to the removed (from state)
                        style={selectedAnswerByUser.includes(answer.id) ? selectedStyle : defaultStyle}
                        >{answer.text}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem that stuck me since days is that I can store the selected answers for each question, but I did not manage the condition for which each question can have only one selected answer.
Each answer should have one answer only, in order to submit the selection at the end of the game and elaborate the score. As far as It shouldn't be a big deal, is giving me very hard time to nail the right logic.

I feel like the problem could be either:

1. The `toggle` function: I currently update the state by checking if the selected answer is already selected, thus I remove it. Else, I add it to the array. The method include() returns a boolean and basically is storing in state whatever I click since `answer.id` it is always `true`. This does not allow me to differentiate from the number of selected answers in the answers object.
2. The `style` property with the conditional rendering logic. Similarly to above, every time `answer.id` is `true`, it kicks in the styling and leave it there until I click another time to deselect it.

Any feedback or suggestion will be really appreciated, thank you upfront to whoever will take the time to look into it and have a thought to share.